# How do I render data inside an html string in Vue, before it is displayed?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an html string that contains some variables wrapped in {{}}. Is there a way to trigger the parsing of the html to replace {{}} with values that are present in the teamplate already

```
<div v-html="desc"></div>
```

```
desc = "<p>Some text {{aVar}}</p>"
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
v-html="parse(desc)"
```

and {{aVar}} be replaced with the actual value that is available
Hopefully there is Vue method to do this, but I can definitely use a custom method and replace the values myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For now I solved it with

```
function parseHtml(html = "") {
      const expose = {
        player,
      };
      return html.replace(/{{(.+?)}}/g, (_, g) => {
        return _get(expose, g);
      });
    }
```

where _get is the lodash _.get

Answer (score 0):

[Like this?](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const msg = ref('Hello World!')
const parse = (text) => (`<span style=\"color:red\">${text}<span>`)
</script>
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="msg">
  <div v-html="parse(msg)"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Well not sure, my actual hello world text is something like
 Hello World! {{test.var1}} and I want to replace {{test.var1}} with the value inside test = {var1: "some var 1 text" }

Comment: That is not possible with Vue.

Comment: looks like dynamic components can make it work, just not sure how. Examples show did not work for me but still working on it(or a custom parser)

Answer (score 0):

With inspiration from your example @orbitory
What about this?

**Options API**

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      template: `<p> {{ message }} {{ message2 }}</p>`,
      message: "hello",
      message2: "world",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    parse(html) {
      return html.replace(/{{(.+?)}}/g, (_, g) => {
        return this[g.trim()];
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
    <input v-model="message">
    <input v-model="message2">
    <div v-html="parse(template)" />
</template>
```

Demo with reactive input fields example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/how-do-i-render-data-inside-an-html-string-in-vue-before-it-is-displayed-x8oq1?file=/src/App.vue

---

**Composition API**

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
let template = "<p> {{ message }} {{ message2 }} </p>"
let message = ref('hello')
let message2 = ref('world')

let data = { message, message2 }
function parse(html) {
  return html.replace(/{{(.+?)}}/g, (_, g) => {
    return this[g.trim()].value;
  });
}
parse = parse.bind(data)
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="message">
  <input v-model="message2">
  <div v-html="parse(template)"></div>
</template>
```

Demo with reactive input fields - based on @tauzN example.

[link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: I am using the composition api, .this is not available for me so had to expose some vars. Maybe there is another way to expose this but I think just having a separate object might be better. For me the object path looks like game.player.name or oponent.endurance

Comment: I have updated with a Composition API example also. @orbitory